# How can I comment code in a Wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I don't want to display the code inside `if` statement in Wordpress template even if condition is true.

```
<?php   if($can_follow_company): ?> 

    Code

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: use `/* Code */` ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: Hm,it didn't worked,it just added the /* and */ symbols to the theme.Any more suggestions?THanks

Comment: because of the if statement style here, you'd have to add the brackets around your comment.  for example:  `<?php /*  some code or comments */ ?>`

Comment: I just want to comment out the code out of execution.Any more suggestions?I mean I don't want the if statement (with the Code included) to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment it in the same way as you do in a functions file or in a class file.

Below you can find different approaches:

First Method

```
<?php /* Put a comment here */ >
<?php   if($can_follow_company): ?> 

    Code

<?php endif; ?>
```

Second Method (A more beautiful comment with annonations):

```
<?php
 /**
  * @todo lorem ipsum
  * @Author 
  */
>
<?php   if($can_follow_company): ?> 

    Code

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also put the comment just before the if statement, but for second option is what is defined as the best way to comment and document `PHP` code as in this way you can use your IDE or tools to generate documentation https://www.phpdoc.org/.

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

If you need to just not execute the **Code** part you just need to add a false to if statement. Your code would be like this;

```
<?php   if($can_follow_company && false): ?> 

    Code

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but actually I want to comment the code out of execution.

Comment: What do you mean with out of execution?

Comment: I mean I don't want the Code to be executed.So instead of deleting all the if statement,I just want to add it as comment so it won't be executed.Thanks

Comment: In that case you have ask the question in a wrong way. The PHP comment is done in this way.

Comment: I added the "&& false" in the if condition and the code never executed.That's what I wanted to achieve.thanks

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it helped you :)